# How to resume nginx caching without restarting nginx after purge

Tags: cache, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using fastcgi cache with nginx 1.4.4 on fedora and it works great until I clear the cache directory with:

```
find /var/nginx/cache -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Thereafter nginx will not resume caching any requests until nginx is restarted.

According to [Igor](http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/best-way-to-empty-nginx-cache-td3017271.html) a restart is not necessary. So how can I get nginx to resume caching without restarting it?

Here's my virtual host file:

```
fastcgi_cache_path  /var/nginx/cache levels=1:2 
                    keys_zone=PAGE_CACHE:60m 
                    inactive=60m; 
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri"; 
fastcgi_buffers 256 4k; 
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status; 

server { 
    listen 80 default; 
    server_name localhost; 
    root /var/www/website/root; 
    location = /favicon.ico { 
            return 204; 
          } 
    location ~* \.(php|cgi|asp|aspx|jsp)$ { 
        return 404; 
    } 
    try_files $uri @fcgi; 
    location @fcgi { 
        fastcgi_cache PAGE_CACHE; 
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 5m; 
        limit_conn tenmins 3; 
        limit_req zone=gulag burst=50 nodelay; 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/fastcgi.socket; 
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this in my nginx.conf:

```
sendfile off;
```

And a system restart solved the issue.